# static value changes to first value when a new object is created

Tags: java, variables, object, static

I have two static integer value and i am drawing mini circles for creating digital representation of letters on the frame,
I have to use class for each letter just once. My problem is the cordinates which are X:100 Y: 100 on beginning in Draw class have same value after creating object draw2 but it should be x:165 y:100 the numbers are increasing in Draw class. How can i fix this problem?

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Draw draw = new Draw('A');
    frame.add(draw);
    Draw draw2 = new Draw(' ');
    frame.add(draw2);
```

Draw Class

```
public class Draw  extends JPanel{
boolean[][] letterArray;
static int X = 100, Y = 100;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your description is very unclear. It's also unclear why your variables are static at all. Please post a short but complete demonstration of the problem, and explain what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I have to keep cordinates in class and my X cordinate have to change, because i have to create 12 object from Draw class and each object just will create one digital letter representation. This is homework and this is wanted from us

Comment: It's still not at all clear why you need static variables, I'm afraid. I would specify the location when you create the `Draw` object. And although you've now posted *some* more code, it's far from a short but complete program.

Comment: That's *still* not a [mcve], and you still haven't properly explained why you think you need static variables.

Comment: topic can  be deleted

Comment: So you should hit the "delete" link at the bottom of the question. Others would have to wait for it to be closed, then vote to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

A static variable is bound to the class. In contrast to a normal member variable, which is bound to its owning instance.

```
class ExampleA {
    static int value; // a class member
}

class ExampleB {
    int value;  // an object member
}

ExampleA a1 = new ExampleA(), a2 = new ExampleA();
ExampleA.value = 10;
System.out.println("a1.value=" + a1.value);  // 10
System.out.println("a2.value=" + a2.value);  // 10

a1.value = 25;  // changes ExampleA.value really
System.out.println("a1.value=" + a1.value);  // 25
System.out.println("a2.value=" + a2.value);  // 25

ExampleB b1 = new ExampleB(), b2 = new ExampleB();
b1.value = 5;
b2.value = 10;
System.out.println("b1.value=" + b1.value);  //  5
System.out.println("b2.value=" + b2.value);  // 10
```

In other words: all instances of `ExampleA` share the same `value` variable. But each instance of `ExampleB` has its own `value` variable.

Comment: Yes i am using this property but when i create an instance static values are get the 100 value again in this project but i tried it another class it is working ordinarily